# Disable pointer events on an img tag angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am relatively new to Angularjs and I am trying to figure out the most appropriate way to remove pointer events since ng-disable still allows a click event. This iswhat I have with no success:

**html**

```
  <img class="btn btn-primary" style="border: none; margin-top: 0px;"
             src="assets/img/test-22x22.png"
             ng-class="path !== '/begin' && path !== '/end'?{'pointer-events': 'none'}:{}">
```

Comment: ele.css"pointer-event", "none", or toggle a class css with angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-style with your code:

```
<img class="btn btn-primary" style="border: none; margin-top: 0px;"
             src="assets/img/test-22x22.png"
             ng-style="path !== '/begin' && path !== '/end'?{'pointer-events': 'none'}:{}">
```

OR add class with some values like and use it

```
.no-pointer-class {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events:none;
}

<img class="btn btn-primary" 
     style="border: none; margin-top: 0px;"
     src="assets/img/test-22x22.png"
     ng-class="{'no-pointer-class': (path !== '/begin' && path !== '/end')}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set cursor:not-allowed from css style for img element`**<img style="cursor:not-allowed;">**`